# С помощью каких инструментов можно массово генерировать скриншоты?

Tags: javascript, python, php, сервер

Нужно раз в неделю делать массовую генерацию скриншотов нескольких сотен сайтов и сохранять в папку на сервере. Причем нужно делать скриншоты только видимой части сайта в размере 1366х600рх. На каких языках это можно реализовать?

Comment: да думаю на любом, тут как раз вопрос другой больше подходит. Какие библиотеки на языке X нужно использовать?